# a written expression test in mba entrance i don't understand

Tags: grammar

Following is a test of MBA entrance.

The answer sheet says number 1 has to be changed but why?

[image]

Comment: I guess "THE" needs to be omitted. Since modern cosmology is the name of an academic subject and no article is necessary before them.

Comment: but when i search google with "the modern cosmology" i get a lot of usage for this combination

Comment: i guess i get it now,  the sentence is speaking generally about "modern cosmology" not a special one, and that's why we don't need article "the" in this "context".
thanks jain

Comment: :) glad that helped. Shall I write it as an answer?

Comment: why not? go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why number 1 has to be changed is **The**, it needs to be omitted.

> Modern cosmology is a **mathematical physics subject**.

It is an academic subject and no article is necessary before it.

*Source for the definition of Modern Cosmology: Wikipedia*

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say:

> She studies *the Ancient History*.

but we can say

> She studies *the ancient history* of Rome.

When referring to an academic subject *by name*,  the adjective before the noun is the specifier:

> He studies Old Norse.

and  **the** is not used together with the adjective specifier.

But when referring to the subject not by name, but as an area of research or interest, the adjective functions merely a modifier, thus *the ancient history of Rome*.